# Conditional Formatting iwork Numbers

Tags: iwork, apple-numbers

I am trying to create a spreadsheet in iWork 09 Numbers. I have values in cells along with dates, however until this date is passed I don't want the corresponding value to be included in the final "total" formula which adds all the values together.

Below is the formula for one of the cells, this works fine but it shows the cell value as zero, I want it to set it as zero but show 350. So that it still calculates the total correctly, but by always showing 350 as the value.

```
=IF(A7<=TODAY(),350,0) =VALUE("350")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.. This is not going to work for you. The problem is that you cant have a formula that refers to itself as the determining value to become part of the new formula. That is, it has to be conditional, and it can only display the value to which the formula refers.

If you want that cell to show the value 350, then put the first part of the formula into a separate cell (or table, sheet, whatever). Then, in the cell you want to display as 350, put

```
=IF('Cell that works out if A7<=TODAY(), 350, "Error")
```

Should get you the result you want.'